# How do I search for lead or account using Dynamics CRM SDK?

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

Can someone please provide a sample code for retrieving leads by email in CRM SDK? Is there any built in function that works like this?

```
Guid leadID = someLeadManager.GetByEmail(email);
```

Comment: Is the *email* value used to retrieve entities a full and exact address or do you need to use matching?

Comment: I needed only exact address, but thx very much for providing details on filtration for a match of part of the email.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming that you've obtained the *service*, you can execute the following query.

```
private Guid GetGuidByEmail(String email)
{
  QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
  {
    EntityName = "lead",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("emailaddress1"),
    Criteria = new FilterExpression
    {
      Filters =
      {
        new FilterExpression
        {
          Conditions =
          {
            new ConditionExpression(
              "emailaddress1", ConditionOperator.Equals, email)
          }
        }
      }
    }
  };

  Entity entity = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities.FirstOrDefault();
  if(entity != null)
    return entity.Id;
  return Guid.Empty;
}
```

Now, if you need filtration for a match of **part** of the email, the query gets shorter, and instead, you can do the selection using LINQ like this.

```
private IEnumerable<Guid> GetGuidsByEmail(String email)
{
  QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
  {
    EntityName = "lead",
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet("emailaddress1")
  };
  IEnumerable<Entity> entities = service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;

  return entities
    .Where(element => element.Contains("emailaddress1"))
      .Where(element => Regex.IsMatch(element["emailaddress1"], email))
        .Select(element => element.Id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to retrieve leads that have a specific mail? Something like this can be done in that case.

```
private EntityCollection GetLeadsWithEmail(
  IOrganizationService service, String wantedEmailAddress)
{
  QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
  query.EntityName = "lead";
  // the columns you want
  query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet() { AllColumns = true };

  query.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
  query.Criteria.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
  query.Criteria.Conditions.Add(new ConditionExpression(
    "emailaddress1", ConditionOperator.Equal, wantedEmailAddress));
  return service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
}
```

This will retrieve all the leads that have wantedEmailAddress in their emailaddress1 field.
You can then check if there were any matches from where you called it;

```
EntityCollection leadCollection = GetLeadsWithEmail(
  service, "someone@example.com");
Entity entity = leadCollection[0];
```

You probably should first check the number of entities in the collection with `leadCollection.Entities.Count` and continue from there.

[Here's a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328149.aspx) from MSDN.

Comment: +1 for query expression and modularization. He should however use LINQ and a *foreach* to ensure that even the 0th element doesn't crash his execution. It seems unnecessary to use the *LogicalOperator* if he's only got one condition. It's not recommended to fetch all the columns (I make the mistake of forgetting to check against missing values because of that).